# Загадочное слово "по-моему".

Tags: лексическая

Здравствуйте! Интересное в голову пришло, и вот решил спросить.

Слово *по-моему* (с ударением на гласную У) имеет значение вводного слова (синонимы: на мой взгляд, по моему мнению и т.д). По-моему (= на мой взгляд), Женя позабыл о той встрече.

Слово *по-моему* (с ударением на гласную О) имеет значение вводного слова (указывает на степень уверенности. Синонимы: кажется, наверное и т.д).

Считаются ли эти слова омографами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: по-мо́ему нареч.
    1Так, как свойственно мне, как характерно для меня.
    2Так, как я считаю правильным, нужным.
    3разг. На свойственном мне языке.
    4Употребляется как вводное слово, соответствуя по значению сл.: с моей точки зрения, как мне кажется.
     Если это предлог с местоимением "мой" в дательном падеже, то пишется раздельно с ударением на "у", а не на "о". Вы пойдете по моемУ пути. По моему́ мне́нию, настоя́нию

Comment: А я всегда употребляю "по-моемУ" в значении вводного слова, указывающего на моё мнение.

Comment: Да, правильно. Вводное слово употребляется в значении, указывающего  на мнение говорящего. См. в 4-ом значении.Только с ударением на О.

Comment: Поэтому  не  омографы.  Дефис  в  одном  случае  отсутствует.

Comment: Да, не омографы. Это паронимы.